# How to return a boolean value and print a message in python

Tags: python

for example, I want to return a Boolean value False and print a message ("It did not pass the test") at same time in python, how to do that?

Comment: Do you mean in the same statement? you can just have the program print and then return false.

Comment: But I want the message to be printed after  False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
def this_returns_false(<arguments>):
    """
    Do stuff here
    """
    return False

if not this_returns_false(<args>): # not accesses the function for False statement now
    print "It did not pass the test"
```

a possible shorthand:

```
print "It did not pass the test" if not this_returns_false else ""
```

OP's code:

```
def password_check(password): 

    upper_letter = str.upper(lower_letter) 

    if ((count_digit(password) == 0) or (count_Lletter(password) == 0) or (count_Uletter(password) == 0)): 
        return False and print("it did not pass the test")
```

Edit after OP's code:

```
def password_check(password): 

    upper_letter = str.upper(lower_letter) 

    if (not count_digit(password)) or (not count_Lletter(password)) or (not count_Uletter(password)):  
        # not is the same as !

        print("it did not pass the test")
        return False
```

The `print` statement is executed before the return statement here btw.

Comment: is it possible to put flase and the printed message at same line> because my function have to output them after one case

Comment: your function is like...what exactly?

Comment: my function is like this def password_check(password):
    upper_letter = str.upper(lower_letter)
    if ((count_digit(password) == 0) 
    or (count_Lletter(password) == 0) 
    or (count_Uletter(password) == 0)):
        return False and print("it did not pass the test")

Comment: so I have to output them after the first case, but I don't know the correct format to write it

Comment: If it worked (which it looks like it did), do mark the answer as `accepted` and `upvote` it for others to view. :)

Comment: got another problem, if I got the function called    def foo(sample), and at end I want to print ((sample) did not pass test), how to keep the variable "sample" in the original form after printed?

Comment: you can do that using: `def foo(sample):
<<<do something>>>
print (str(sample) + " did not pass the test")`

Comment: Haha. Not a problem. Cheers.